# Jquery Dialogue isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a custom alert by using jquery dialogue and currently on click submit (with id=submit) it checks to see if the value of id choose_client = "" and if so, prompt dialogue box and not process form.
What its doing instead is processing the form instead AND not even showing the dialogue. Any ideas why? Here is my code:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        if($('#choose_client').val() == ''){
            $("<div title='Invoice Error'>Please Choose A Client</div>").dialog();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

html:

```
<form method="post" action="new_invoice.php">
Client: <select id="choose_client" name="client">
<option name="client_none" value="">Choose A Client</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="step" disabled>
</form><br />
```

Comment: When running the app, always open the developer tools console so you can see the errors.

Answer (score 2):

In order for `event.preventDefault();` to work, you need to pass `event` as an argument:

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Post your HTML and any other JavaScript you have.

Comment: Its a large js file with secure information that I cant post =/. I have that function within document ready but even taking it out of document ready doesn't work.

Comment: What I'm confused most about is that the dialogue doesn't even show up. It ignores it and processes the form.

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: The only console errors are: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function iprocess.js:22
(anonymous function) iprocess.js:22
b.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
v.handle